# FTP Connection and file transfer through putty

Tags: ftp, putty

can we use psftp to download, upload, list ...etc from ftp account. as it always gives me connection time out when trying to connect using connection batch like..

"c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\psftp" -v -l [USER]-pw [Password]-P 21 [HOST] -b %1

Answer (score 1):

PSFTP is not a FTP client, it is a SFTP client. [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) and FTP are not the same thing. SFTP typically uses port 22 and is completely different than FTP.

[Here is an article](http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/75602/Understanding-Key-Differences-Between-FTP-FTPS-and-SFTP) that provides some information on the differences between FTP and SFTP (and FTPS).